# how can apply none property on anchor tag in html

Tags: html, css, safari, css-selectors

I am trying apply none property on anchor tag using CSS. like "www.google.com,". Whoever clicks on this link should take no action. It's working fine in Chrome. It's not working on the Safari browser. I even try -webkit but still facing issue. Here is the CSS that I am implementing.

```
pointer-events: none !important;
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent ! important;
 cursor: not-allowed !important;
-webkit-user-select: none !important;
```

Comment: Are you applying it directly to `<a>`? What version of Safari? Check if the version is supported with https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer-events

Comment: No basically using it on <a> class named "products_data" .

Comment: I am applying class on anchor tag and in the class I added the CSS which I mentioned above.

Comment: Let me know which classes I should apply that will fix the issue for all Safari browser versions.

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-user-select: none; - can't be selected

pointer-events: none; - can't be clicked

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events